# Windows WMI -- find a unique identifier for each hardware component?

Tags: windows, winapi, wmi, hardware, unique

I'm currently writing an application that retrieves hardware information about a computer.

I need some sort of unique identifier for each hardware component, such as an UID or S/N. I can see this "DeviceID" member in almost every component (inherited from [CIM_LogicalDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), and it says:

> "Address or other identifying information to uniquely name the logical device."

Sounds good! Does this mean that it's unique for just that specific computer; or is it unique for "all computers in the world" (which is what I need).

Thanks!

Comment: It is unique to that machine and setup. Some devices have a serial number that you can query but it's far from most.

Comment: @Deanna By unique to that machine, do you mean that two different computers cannot have the same DeviceID for a specific component. Or do you mean that it's only unique in that particular machine, and it can, on other computers, have the same DeviceID?

Yes, I know about the S/N on some devices (I'm using them already), but I'm also looking for a unique name for all the other devices.

Comment: Also, will it be persistent if you re-install your computer OS?

Comment: It will be the same on that machine only. Other devices may have the same ID on other machines, and that same device may have a different device ID on other machines. On a reinstall, it's effectively a new machine so may (or may not) have the same device ID again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was not the best way of uniqely name a device, since it COULD be the same UID across different computers.

Instead, I collected a whole bunch of data from each components in the computer (motherboard, CPU, GPU, memory, NIC etc.), hashed them with MD5 to create a sort of "identifier". Works pretty well.